# functional component declare using fat arrow becomes undefined after import in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I declare this functional component in react but when I import this component in another component It throws an error that this component is undefined and when I change this **fat arrow** functional to normal ES5 function, it works! why ???

```
export default ActionButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusSquare} className={classes.ButtonItem} />
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? My guess would be you have a circular dependency issue here, and proper function declarations are hoisted, but I would expect you to get a temporal dead zone exception not an `undefined` value.

Comment: Notice that you are accidentally assigning to a `ActionButton` variable, which should really throw an exception in strict mode if that was not already declared elsewhere. Are you actually doing `export default (props) => {…};` or maybe `const ActionButton = (props) => { … }; export default ActionButton;` or even `const ActionButton = (props) => { … }; export {ActionButton as default}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining separately with `const` then exporting the created `ActionButton` variable as:

```
const ActionButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusSquare} className={classes.ButtonItem} />
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ActionButton
```

Then you can import in the other component as - probably the path is different:

```
import ActionButton from './ActionButton'
```

Comment: I will try it with const but why it show undefined before without const

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export default like:

```
export default ActionButton = (props) => {
```

You should do this instead:

```
export default (props) => {
```

It's because default export has no name explicitly. That is, you can import it by any name.

---

However, preferred method is to define first and export later: (If you have other named exports as well)

```
const ActionButton = (props) => {}
export default ActionButton
```